# synchronization in java (object and static methods)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, synchronization

I have few queries regarding Synchronization in Java. I have read a lot of content online and have feeded myself with lot of information and so with multiple doubts.
I will list down my queries, so please anyone help me out with my doubts.

**Object level synchronization :**

1) For following code sample.

```
public synchronized void a(){
    //todo
    }
}
```

What will be the LOCK used. Will it automatically be lock on "this" as we have it in case below sample code ?

```
public void a(){
    synchronized (this) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

2) We have multiple methods code blocks locking on "this".

```
public void a(){
    synchronized (this) {
        //TODO
    }
}
public synchronized void b(){
    synchronized (this) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

So does this means that if code block of b() is locked, then any other thread wont be able to access a() as well at the same time as they have a lock on the object(this)?

**Class level synchronization :**

3) For the following code

```
public static void c(){

synchronized (Main.class) {
        //todo
    }
}public static void d(){
    synchronized (Main.class) {
        //todo
    }
}public static void e(){
    //no syncronization here
}
```

Question 1 : IF c() is locked will any other thread be able to access d() which has synchronized block as well ?
Question 2: If c() is under lock, will any other thread will be able to access e() which is a non synchronized method ?

Comment: I would try them if I were you.

Comment: also try with some meaningful code..will help you to understand better..you are nearly there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes "this" is the lock
2. Yes
3. The lock is on Main.class so if the lock in c is already acquired d can't be accessed by another thread.

in point 3. e() can always be accessed by multiple threads no matter what since its not synchronized.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: if we make methods in question 3 as non-static methods and we have lock on "this"...then what will happen in this case ...  will e() be available for access being unsynchronized ?

Comment: also for your reply on question 3...if d() and e() both gets locked..then would it also imply even method c() wont be able to make a call to d() or e() inside synchronization block ?

Comment: didn't pay attention that e() is not synchronized see modified answer.